# How do I render the selected options differently compared to those in the list with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using a react-select multi select where I would like to provide more information on the label when in the dropdown to make it easier to pick the right one, but when it has been selected I want to render a shorter version to save space.

For example, in the drop down I might want to print something like `12321 - item - something more`, but when it has been selected I'm satisfied with only `item`. I still want to keep the deselect functionality.

I've tried `formatOptionLabel` but that will change the rendering in both places.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to create a component for `MultiValueLabel`

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return (<div>{props.data.label}</div>)
};

<Select 
    components={{ MultiValueLabel: MyComponent }}
    ....
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for SingleValue

```js
const MySingleValue = ({children, ...props}) => {
    // props.data.label to get the chosen option label.
    return (<components.SingleValue {...props}>
                {// show what you need instead of the label of the selected option}
           </components.SingleValue>)

<Select 
    components={{ SingleValue: MySingleValue }}
    ....
/>
};
```

You can read more about react-select components [here](https://react-select.com/components)